# Shift of even periodic function

Tags: analysis

When we shift $\sin(x)$ by $\pi$ (half the period) we get an odd function $-\sin(x)$.
I was wondering if every periodic, even function can be made odd if we shift it by half it's period?

I guess this is not the case but I wasn't able to come up with a good counter example..

Comment: How about $1+\cos x$?

Comment: It it actually so simple..Thanks

Comment: @Bernard yes corrected it.

Comment: You forget $\sin x $ is odd, not even.

Comment: No, not generally.  First, Lubin's comment is correct.  Second, $\sin x$ is special because it is anti-symmetric about 0 *and* half its period.  That's why your shift works.  There's no reason in general that a periodic function would have that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be noticing is that $\sin(x)$ is odd, and
$\cos(x)$ is even and the second is a shifted version of the first by a quarter of a period. This generalizes. Suppose we have a function  $f(x)$ defined on an interval $\ [0,L].\ $ Define an extension to $\ [L,2L]\ $ with the reversed function $\ f(2L-x).\ $ Extend even further to $\ [2L,4L]\ $ with $\ -f(x-2L).\ $ Finally, extend periodically to all real numbers with $\ f(x) = f(x+4nL)\ $ for all integer $n$. The extended period $\ 4L\ $ function $\ f(x)\ $ is odd, the shifted function $\ f(x+L)\ $ is even, and the twice shifted function $\ f(x+2L) = -f(x)\ $ is also odd.

However, if a **non-zero** non-negative periodic function is even, then **no** shift of it will be odd because that would require it to take on negative values which we excluded by assumption. The simplest case is any non-zero constant function. It is an even function and has all periods, but no shift of it can be an odd function.

Comment: Thanks! Makes alot more sense now.